# How to show only column subtotal in power bi table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a table like [image: this] and I would like to see only the subtotal column. Is this even possible in power bi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For your measure, you need to write it in the form:

```
IF(HASONEVALUE('Table'[ColumnwithC]), BLANK(), [yourmeasure])
```

Comment: is it also possible for matrix ? for that i need to create a new questions ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible in a matrix. I suggest you write a new question but provide either sample data or a sample .pbix to better help you.

Comment: i will do that, thanks a lot.